# Como puedo imprimir un Char en lenguaje C?

Tags: array, c, printf

tengo que hacer un programa en C que al ingresar un numero n imprima:

```
1

12

123

1234

1234...n
```

tengo entendido que en C no se puede asignar el tamaño de un array por teclado asi que mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
void main(){
   int i,n;
   char A[100];
   scanf("%i",&n);

   for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
   {
        A[i] = i+1;
        printf(" %s\n", A); 
   }
}
```

pero cuando lo ejecuto me imprime esto:

```
?

??

???

????...n
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por curiosidad, ¿te obligan a usar un array para eso? Lo digo porque no lo necesitas, basta con dos for anidados. Y si puedes asignar el tamaño de un array por teclado, usando memoria dinámica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para imprimir en [c](/questions/tagged/c) un carácter, debes usar `%c` en la función `printf`:

```
printf("%d\n", 42); // Imprime el número '42'
printf("%c\n", 42); // Imprime el carácter '*'
```

Pero no necesitas eso para tu ejercicio, basta con multiplicar y sumar:

```
int longitud, numero = 0;
scanf("%i",&longitud);

for (int i = 0; i != longitud; ++i)
{
    numero *= 10;
    numero += i;
}
```

> tengo entendido que en C no se puede asignar el tamaño de un array por teclado

Supongo que te refieres a que no se puede asignar el tamaño de un array mediante un tamaño pedido por teclado al usuario. Si es así, no es cierto que no se pueda:

```
int tamanyo;
scanf("%d", tamanyo);

char *array = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * tamanyo);
```

Puedes pedir memoria con `malloc` (***m***emory **alloc**ation, alojamiento de memoria), pero si lo haces deberás liberarla al final con `free` (liberar):

```
free(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos correcciones:

1. Realizar correctamente la conversión de `int` a `char` antes de almacenar el valor, tomando en cuenta el código ASCII y...
2. Agregar un carácter nulo `'\0'` en la posición `i+1`, para indicar que en esta posición termina el string.

---

```
//1
A[i] = i+'1';
//2
A[i+1]='\0';
```

**NOTA:**

Esto es válido solo para `n` de un solo dígito, es decir, el máximo valor de `n` sería 9.